# How to create a physical storage table in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have created a new dataset with physical billing enabled:

```
CREATE SCHEMA `project1.test_physical_storage`
  OPTIONS (
    default_partition_expiration_days = 29,
    default_table_expiration_days = 29,
    description = 'Testing physical storage ',
    location = 'US',
    max_time_travel_hours = 48,
    storage_billing_model = PHYSICAL
  );
```

Then I tried creating a new table in this dataset

```
create table `test_physical_storage.tabl1` (id int, name string) ;
insert into `test_physical_storage.tabl1` values(1,'abc'), (2,'xyz');
```

But I see that the table only has logical bytes. It doesnt have physical bytes.

[image]

**Edit:**
After some time I was able to see physical bytes too. But there are still logical bytes. Shouldnt logical bytes become 0 ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is based on my discussion with GCP support:

- Each table will show both logical and physical bytes irrespective of its `storage_billing_model`
- If storage_billing_model = PHYSICAL then we will be charged only for physical storage
- If storage_billing_model = LOGICAL (which is by default) then we will be charged only for logical storage.
- It takes couple of minutes for the table stats to update.

Answer (score 0):

Storage billing model of a dataset is set to LOGICAL by default, by updating to logical you will have to wait for about 24 hrs to take effect:

> When you change a dataset's billing model, it takes 24 hours for the change to take effect.

You can visit this article for more information about Storage billing models:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-datasets#sql_4

Comment: I created a new dataset with Physical storage type. I did not update a pre-existing logical dataset.

Comment: It is possible that these logical bytes are metadata for that table, Even then you will only be charge with physical bytes that you see in your table details, See formula that is posted in these article: `((ACTIVE_PHYSICAL_BYTES value / POW(1024, 3)) * active physical bytes pricing) + ((LONG_TERM_PHYSICAL_BYTES value / POW(1024, 3)) * long-term physical bytes pricing)`

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-table-storage#forecast_storage_billing